# Flat Ui in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am using Flat Ui in my Android Application using Android Studio but i am unable to find AutoCompleteTextView inside Flat Ui and I have to use AutoCompleteTextview in my application so anyone suggest me the way to use that?

Answer (score 1):

I Just fork a library for AutoCompleteTextView and waiting to be merged.

For now:

1. Inside library/src/main/java/com/cengalabs/flatui/views create new file name it FlatAutoCompleteTextView.java
2. Find the FlatEditText.java copy the content and paste it to FlatAutoCompleteTextView.java
3. Inside FlatAutoCompleteTextView.java replace all text with "FlatEditText" with "FlatAutoCompleteTextView" .
4. find this part style = a.getInt(R.styleable.fl_FlatAutoCompleteTextView_fl_fieldStyle, 0); and replace with style = a.getInt(R.styleable.fl_FlatAutoCompleteTextView_fl_autoFieldStyle, 0);
5. Edit library/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml , paste this code inside and save or just replace content with this http://pastebin.com/w4w5UWdd

To use style fl_autoFieldStyle="flat" or fl_autoFieldStyle="box"

Answer (score 0):

If [the Flat UI project](https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI) does not support `AutoCompleteTextView`, your choices are:

1. Write it yourself.
2. Convince the author of the library to write it for you.
3. Hire some other developer to write it for you.
4. Go without `AutoCompleteTextView`.
5. Go without Flat UI.

Since none of the Flat UI widgets are based on `AdapterView`, creating an `AutoCompleteTextView` may be rather complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The merge request from [PinoyWebDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2493806/pinoywebdev) (thanks to him) is closed and AutoCompleteTextView is now available in the library. You can see the added class [here](https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/cengalabs/flatui/views/FlatAutoCompleteTextView.java).