# How to use android flat ui eluleci?

Tags: android, flatui

Does anybody know how to use this flat ui for android ?

[GITHUB-LINK](https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI)

There are no proper docs plus no tutorials also , I want to create the flat buttons also apply themes cant find anything .

Comment: That link it self holding samples.

Comment: Can't you see that sample folder given in that repository?

Comment: eluleci has provided sample also https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI/tree/master/sample

Comment: i apparently didnt see that :P srry and thnx and if theres more please link it here.

Comment: Check this once
[Flat Ui in Android Studio]
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192771/flat-ui-in-android-studio/25772188#25772188

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample project which is from the same library:

[FLAT UI Sample project](https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI/tree/master/sample/src/main)